# XAMPP PHP and Mongo DB connection authentication failed on database admin

Tags: php, mongodb

I am a beginner in PHP and i am looking forward to make a connection from XAMPP php (local machine) and Mongo DB(remote machine). Please find the details below.

Note: I have already setup the mongo db extension and added the .dll file.
`<?php
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://prizmaUser:Si$ney12#@10.xxx.xxx.238:27017");
?>`

And the result i am getting is

'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: 10.xxx.xxx.238:27017: SASL Authentication failed on database 'admin': Authentication failed.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testdata\Simplification.php:61 Stack trace: #0 '

I tried to using single quotes to escape the special characters in password field. Stil iam getting error. Any help would be highly appreciated.!!!!

Comment: You are using mongodb on localhost?

Comment: No...Mongo DB is in a different remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says 'Authentication failed on database 'admin': Authentication failed.', which means the user prizmaUser with password Si$ney12# does not exist in the admin database. This means that the user was created in a specific database.
Suppose that your database name is testdb, your connection should be

```
$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://prizmaUser:Si$ney12#@10.xxx.xxx.238:27017/testdb', array('authSource' => 'testdb'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your mongo.conf if "net: bindIp: 0.0.0.0" is there.